# Extract a string or value based on specific word before and a % sign after in R

Tags: r, string, filtering, text-mining, text-extraction

I have a Text column with thousands of rows of paragraphs, and I want to extract the values of "`Capacity > x%`". The operation sign can be `>,<,=, ~...` I basically need the operation sign and integer value (e.g. <40%) and place it in a column next to the it, same row. I have tried, removing before/after text, `gsub, grep`, `grepl, string_extract`, etc. None with good results.  I am not sure if the percentage sign is throwing it or I am just not getting the code structure. Appreciate your assistance please.
Here are some codes I have tried (aa is the df, TEXT is col name):

```
str_extract(string =aa$TEXT, pattern = perl("(?<=LVEF).*(?=%)"))

gsub(".*[Capacity]([^.]+)[%].*", "\\1", aa$TEXT)

genXtract(aa$TEXT, "Capacity", "%")

gsub("%.*$", "%", aa$TEXT)

grep("^Capacity.*%$",aa$TEXT)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your dataset ?

Comment: Is the character vector always the same number of characters? IF so, you may be able to use `substr()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gsub solution**

I think your gsub solution was pretty close, but didn't bring along the percentage sign as it's outside the brackets. So something like this should work (the result is assigned to the `capacity` column):

`aa$capacity <- gsub(".*[Capacity]([^.]+%).*", "\\1", aa$TEXT)`

**Alternative method**

The gsub approach will match the whole string when there is no operator match. To avoid this, we can use the stringr package with a more specific regular expression:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

aa %>% 
  mutate(capacity = str_extract(TEXT, "(?<=Capacity\\s)\\W\\s?\\d+\\s?%")) %>%
  mutate(Capacity = str_squish(Capacity)) # Remove excess white space
```

This code will give `NA` when there is no match, which I believe is your desired behaviour.

Comment: Your gsub code captured what I needed.  Is there a way to place NA in case the condition is not met, instead of returning the entire text in the cell, please?  also how can I place the results in a new column next to where this text is located?  Appreciate your assistance very much.

Comment: Edited my answer to reassign the result to the data frame.

Comment: Terrific!  Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not provide a reproducible example, I created one myself and used it here.

We can use `sub` to extract everything after `"Capacity"` until a number and `%` sign.

```
sub(".*Capacity(.*\\d+%).*", "\\1", aa$TEXT)
#[1] " > 10%"  " < 40%"  " ~ 230%"
```

Or with `str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(aa$TEXT, "(?<=Capacity).*\\d+%")
```

**data**

```
aa <- data.frame(TEXT = c("This is a temp text, Capacity > 10%", 
                    "This is a temp text, Capacity < 40%", 
                    "Capacity ~ 230% more text  ahead"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, as your sub code captured most of what I needed, but missed it if there was an = sign vs < or >.  I like the format where it enters a NA if the condition is not met.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @Shawn The solution I posted above is based on my understanding of your data which may or may not be true and that is the reason why you should share a reproducible example which represents your actual data so such edge cases are not missed.

Comment: Oh, I am fully aware of my lack of submission of an example some nuances are definitely lost. I do appreciate your assistance and input and tried your suggested codes to seem the pro/cons.  Honestly, I have reviewed the instructions on providing sample data/examples several times and it doesn't seem to work for my examples.  I appreciate any suggestions you may offer off line, if you have time only.  Thank you again for your support.